# difficulties to "fontFamily" with regard to the wordpress plugin ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) in Flutter App ...(newbie)

Tags: wordpress, flutter, advanced-custom-fields

Unfortunately I am not able to display the text lines of the wordpress plugin ACF ( https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ ) + ( https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-rest-api/ ) in my flutter app in a desired font, unfortunately I don't know how to solve this either. unfortunately only found things in the forum that don't really help me, maybe someone knows advice from you?

This is the way in which the api is integrated with the corresponding text style, which does not seem to work

```
  factory PostModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, CategoryModel category, { List bookmarks = const [] }) {
    int id = int.parse(json['id'].toString());
    final postAuthor = json['author_info']['display_name'].toString();
    String secondTitle = json['acf']['second_title'].toString();
    final postTitle = _getTitle(json['title']['rendered']);
    final postExcerpt = json['excerpt']['rendered'].toString();
    String header =
        '<h4 id="second_title" fontFamily: "Storopia" >$secondTitle</h4>' +
            '<h3 fontFamily: "Storopia">$postTitle</h3>' +
            postExcerpt.replaceAll(
                '</p>', '<h5 fontFamily: "Storopia">Von $postAuthor</h5></p>');
```

this is the way I have included it in the page display, in this case also with text style, but that doesn't work either :-(, even if I have it in both places, unfortunately no success ....

```
          /// ACF Fields (HTML)
          Html(
            data: widget.post.header,
            style: {
              "p": Style(
                fontFamily: "Storopia",
                fontSize: FontSize(14),
                color: isDark ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              ),
            },
          ),
```

Unfortunately, the aforementioned acf fields are not displayed in the desired font, please be patient if I have small errors with the question or something similar, hope you understand who could be where the problem, hope it is possible to solve it ... thank you for reading ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found the Solution for this ... Simply add this to MaterialApp

```
    theme: ThemeData(
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontFamily: "your font"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed the `fontFamily:` installed in your `pubspec.yaml` file. It should look something like this. It is an example and not the exact font of yours so do mind that may vary for you

```
  fonts:
    - family: Amaranth // In Your Case this should be Storopia
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Amaranth-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Amaranth-Bold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Amaranth-BoldItalic.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Amaranth-Italic.ttf
```

And also if you have it then make sure you have the .ttf files of the font in your workspace. If that is also there then check if you have used correct spellings and capitalizations and correct path and extensions under the `fonts:`.
If that also doesn't fix the issue then check if you have typed the correct spelling inside the Wordpress file where you are trying to include the font family.

Comment: it is correctly integrated in pubspec because the font works in the rest of the app correctly ‍♂️, I would have had to write ^^,but thank you for naming a possible source of error ..